# mlr error in randomForestSRC after first run

Tags: r, random-forest, mlr

I have installed Java 9.0.4 and all the relevant R libraries on macOS 10.13.4 to run the following script in R 3.5.0 (invoked in RStudio 1.1.423):

```
options("java.home"="/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-9.0.4.jdk/Contents/Home/lib")
Sys.setenv(LD_LIBRARY_PATH='$JAVA_HOME/server')
dyn.load('/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-9.0.4.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/server/libjvm.dylib')

library(mlr)
library(tidyverse) # for ggplot and data wrangly
library(ggvis) # ggplot visualisation in shiny app
library(rJava)
library(FSelector)

data <- read.csv('week07/PhishingWebsites.csv')

# All variables to nominal (PhishingWebsites)
data[c(1:31)] <- lapply(data[c(1:31)] , factor)

# Configure a classification task and specify Result as the target feature.
classif.task <- makeClassifTask(id = "web", data = data, target = "Result")


fv <- generateFilterValuesData(classif.task)
```

It works fine the first time I run it, but if I run it a second time I get the following error:

> ```
> Error in randomForestSRC::rfsrc(getTaskFormula(task), data = getTaskData(task),  : 
>   An error has occurred in the grow algorithm.  Please turn trace on for further analysis.
> ```

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: I've been using randomForestSRC directly, which doesn't require Java. One of the two final functions most likely has a trace argument. It is set to FALSE. The message suggests that you set it to TRUE.

Comment: randomForestSRC in mlr doesn't require Java. Have you tried running randomForestSRC directly on the task?

Comment: You are correct. Java is not required (it was required to install some dependencies). Once I commented out the first three lines the error does no longer come up.